# C# picturebox causes whole form to freeze up and load forever

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm not sure whats happening, but whenever I try to load an image dynamically from a different thread, it will cause my whole form to just freeze up and load forever.  Here is how I'm calling it:

A new thread will call this with a path to an image, such as newimages\0.jpg

```
public void setImage(String imgPath)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgPath);
            screenshotBox.InvokeEx(a => a.Image = bmp);
        }

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Server
{
    static class ISynchronizeInvokeExtensions
    {
        public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
            }
            else
            {
                action(@this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happends when you change screenshotBox.InvokeEx(a => a.Image = bmp); to screenshotBox.InvokeEx(a => a.Image = new Bitmap(imgPath));

Comment: I get the exact same problem, unfortunately :(  I'm developing a chatroom where users can send screenshots to each other, I'm not sure what the error could be.  I'm converting the screenshots to jpeg before I send them- could this be a problem?

Comment: can you show the code that creates the thread, or even better, a whole example that exhibits the issue? Is it possible your main ui thread is waiting for the thread to complete?

Comment: I am using BeginReceive in C#. I'm straight up calling setImage from the BeginReceived callback